# What are all the recipes obtainable from NPCs?

Tags: fantasy-life

I know there are some recipes that have to be obtained from NPCs since I got the Silver Sword recipe from an NPC in Port Puerto. Are there any other recipes that have to be unlocked before I can craft them?

Answer (score 1):

This list is far too long to post as an answer, but there are some guidelines to follow if you want to make sure to be able to craft everything:

- **Talk to everyone with a question mark above their head**, especially your life master.  These are NPCs that are associated with one of the lives that you have begun, and talking to them occasionally rewards you with an item, recipe, or task.  Sometimes this can be required to rank up!  Other NPCs don't give out recipes as far as I know.
- **Revisit these NPCs when you rank up**.  Every time you rank up, the question marks will reappear above their head which means they have something new to say or give you.  These stack, so **talk to these NPCs until the question mark is gone**.  Since you won't lose anything and this process can take some time, you can wait a few ranks if you don't want to bother with it right away.
- **Enter every building in every town**.  This can be a tiresome process, but sometimes an NPC associated with your life is in a shop associated with a different life.  If you do it enough, you will start to memorize where the NPCs are for your particular life and you won't need to waste time looking in places where you know they aren't.

Unfortunately, you can't get certain recipes until you reach the proper rank, so you can't just visit an NPC once and get everything you want from them.  However, most of the time the rewards aren't essential (sometimes you get nothing), so you can usually wait until you're a master to run around and grab stuff from everybody.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best place I found which lists recipes from NPCs is Wikia (e.g. [Alchemist](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Alchemist)). From what I've seen, they don't yet list EVERYTHING, but have a pretty good list - specially for the NPCs. If you notice you're missing a recipe and it's not listed there, at least you can find the NPCs for that Life and try revisiting them to find the recipe!